# Bool not getting set on click event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I made a simple class in c# that adds two panels on the top, right and left, corners of the form.

If I click the right combination an event is called. The user has 5 seconds to perform the correct combination or it won't work. The combination is "Right, Left, Right".

```
    bool secretCodeStage1;
    bool secretCodeStage2;
        private void TimerReset_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reset();
    }

    private void PanelTopLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (secretCodeStage1 && !secretCodeStage2)
        {
            secretCodeStage2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }

    private void PanelTopRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (secretCodeStage2)
        {
            SecretCodeActivated(this, new EventArgs());

            Reset();
        }
        else
        {
            timerReset.Start();
            secretCodeStage1 = true;
        }
    }
    private void Reset()
    {
        secretCodeStage1 = false;
        secretCodeStage2 = false;

        timerReset.Stop();
    }
```

But there is a funny thing on. If I click Right, Left, Left, Right it works. For some reason by PanelTopLeft_Click, it does set both bools to false, however when the PanelTopRight_Click is called, both bools are still true.

Comment: How quickly are you clicking the left one twice?  Could it be treating your second click as a double click event and therefore not triggering any of the code above (effectively ignoring it)?  (also, should `konamiCodeStage2` be `secretCodeStage2` in your example - seems like a copy/paste/edit issue when you've added the question here)

Comment: I just tested, if I click twice fast it doesn't work (bools don't get set), if I wait 1-2 seconds for the second click it works. But the odd thing is that the reset event gets called.. I set a breakpoint in there and both bools get set to false.

EDIT: Yes, that was a edit issue, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: You may consider tracing the code flow with Debug.Write() statements to see which events are fired in what order and what values your boolean variables have then. Also, when you put a breakpoint to Reset, you can check the callstack to see who is calling Reset (timer, or your event handlers..)

Comment: I think @JamesThorpe found the issue, if I double click, the click event gets called first and then the second click calls the double click event... Go ahead and add a reply so I can accept it. I will add an event for the double click and call the Reset() on it as well.